# Want to read Output Frequency of VFD using Arduino Uno through MAX485

Tags: arduino-uno, modbus, rs485

In my project, I need to read Output Frequency of VFD using arduino Uno through MAX485.

Manual of Delta VFD :- http://www.realimpeks.co.rs/download/delta_vfd_el.pdf

On Page 4-95(138), In 2103H address output frequency data is stored.

I'm confused which library to use and make program for desired result.

Thanks in advance if there's any help given.